# string split <href>

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm new to `Jquery.` I need to extract time and append it at the end of  tag.

```
<html>
5:00 am - 8:am <a href='/sites/ERR/ERR/HC/ERRC Items/DispForm.aspx?ID=4' target="_blank">Implementation of two gateway</a>'
</html>
```

my string should look like below, after formatting: :

```
'<a href='/sites/ERR/ERR/HC/ERRC Items/DispForm.aspx?ID=4' target='_blank">Implementation of two gateway</a> 5:00 am- 8: am '
```

Would you please help ?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can find the time with a simple regular expression and adjust the string:

```js
// INIT TIME STRING
var timeString = "5:00 am - 5: am Implementation of two gateway";

// INIT REGEX
var regex = /\d:\d?\d?\s?(am||pm)?\s?-?\s?\d:\d?\d?\s?(am||pm)?/g;

// PRINT BEFORE
console.log("BEFORE: "+timeString);

// RUN REGEX
match = regex.exec(timeString);

// CHECK IF TIME FOUND
if (match != null) {
  
  // REMOVE TIME VALUE
  timeString = timeString.replace(match[0], "");

  // ADD TIME TO END
  timeString = timeString+" "+match[0];

}

// PRINT AFTER
console.log("AFTER: "+timeString);
```

Comment: @Indu527 No Problem! If this answer helped you please accept it to close the question

Comment: Hi, some of my string contains 5:00 am - 8:am. How do I extract start and end time from my string

Comment: Hey tony, I'm getting the following output:5:00 am Implementation of two Firewalls. I'm expecting output as follows:Implementation of two Firewalls 5:00 am - 8:00 am